# Question regarding the second isomorphism theorem proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I have a question regarding a part of the proof of the second isomorphism theorem.

> Let $I_1, I_2$ be ideals of a ring $R$. Then it's clear that the function $f: I_2 \rightarrow I_1 + I_2 \ / \ I_1$ such that $f(y_2) = \overline{0+y_2}$ is well defined (this is, $f(y_2) \in I_1 + I_2 \ / \ I_1$

I can't see why it is clear that $ \overline{0+y_2} \in I_1 + I_2 \ / \ I_1$.

Comment: The domain of $f$ should be $I_2$, not $I_1$.

Comment: @Bernard fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{0+y_2}=\overline{\vphantom{0}y_2}=y_2+I_1$.

A general element of $(I_1+I_2)/I_1$ is the set of elements of the form $\;y_1+y_2+I_1=y_2+(y_1+I_1)$ ($y_1\in I_1,\:y_2\in I_2$). Now just observe that for any $y_1\in I_1$, one has $\;y_1+I_1=I_1$.

Answer (score 1):

I assuming that 
$$(I_1+I_2)/I_1=\{ \overline{y_1+y_2} \mid y_1 \in I_1, y_2 \in I_2\}$$
so since $0 \in I_1$ for every $y_2 \in I_2$ we have $\overline{0+y_2} \in (I_1+I_2)/I_1$.

Comment: So $(I_1+I_2)/I_1= (I_1+I_2)/I_2$? Because $(I_1+I_2)/I_1=\{ \overline{y_2+y_1} \mid y_1 \in I_1, y_2 \in I_2\}$ and the sum is conmutative in a ring. Is there no difference between both quotient rings?

Comment: @YaggerY of course that equality does not hold. Because the overline has different meaning, in the case of $A/I_1$ you have $\bar y=y+I_1$, in the case of $A/I_2$ you have $\bar y=y+I_2$. I have used the overline notation because that is the notation you used. If that is a problem I can edit the answer.

Comment: I see now, my doubts came from a lack of understanding of the concept of ideal. Thanks for the help.